# High Frequency Polling And Handling Fuzzy Inputs

Tags: input, state, linux

I'm developing a FPS game and I'm considering polling at a high frequency on a separate thread. This decouples the game loop and reading input. I get sub-frame samples and can process those samples from a queue. My question is about determinism. I want to drive input handling with a variation of a state machine or DPDA. These things are not known for "fuzzy-friendliness" so I need to filter dequeued inputs (in the signal processing sense). How do real games implement high frequency input handling?

Comment: What benefit do you hope to gain from polling input faster than your game simulation loop? Or what problem do you have that this would solve? The player can't move or shoot more frequently than the movement and shooting simulation code runs anyway, so most games just read the latest input state once per simulation (or rendering) step, and that's enough for their needs.

Comment: I want as few ms of latency as possible between keystroke and page flip. I also want smooth movement with digital keys. If I can answer "how long was a key down?" I can do that.

Comment: You still need a simulation step to pick up the queued input and convert it into movement of game entities for the next rendering step to display. So just polling your input faster does not improve your latency. Your simulation-render loop is responsible for that. Smooth movement from digital inputs generally does not use timings shorter than a simulation frame, so I doubt you'd find this necessary for that use either.

Comment: Good info. Thank you. Having derivatives in more important to smooth movement, I guess?

Comment: Just accumulating an intensity each simulation tick that a key is held down, or using an acceleration model on your character controller, is usually enough for that. Do you have any problems with your movement being not smooth enough currently? If so, try editing your question to show us how you're moving your character currently, and describe how the outputs differ from what you want. Then we can help you solve that problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I correctly understood your description of the problem, but basically you need a way to (1) combine the input data into a format suitable for your state machine/DPDA to consume, and (2) a way to decouple the rate at which the inputs are coming in from the rate at which you're pulling the data as described in (1). That's something a queue or a stream does (I mean the abstract data type as defined by its operations) - or some variation of it. 1/2

Comment: So, you'd enqueue (or write to stream) raw input, transform it internally, and dequeue (read from stream) a data structure for your state machine; what dequeue/read returns is something like [all keys currently pressed + weight for each key], which I think is what DMGregory is describing (weight = accumulated intensity). This would be one dequeued item (collection of keys) per update cycle. Alternatively, you could chop the output into sub-frame intervals, and dequeue/read into the state machine in a loop (several items per cycle). Does that make sense? 2/2

Comment: Yes. The transform is to map them to abstract symbols and then define the state machine in terms of strings of those symbols. You want to handle the action based on it's priority (at current state - usually encoded implicitly in if-else checks), not based on the order in of the array.